# Difference between an injective function and a function that maps A into B

Tags: functions

Is there any difference between an injective function and a function that maps A into B? If yes, does the difference consist in the fact that a function that maps A into B can fail to be one-to-one, whereas an injective function is always a one-to-one function?

Thanks a lot

Fish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right.

We say $f$ **maps $A$ into $B$** if $f$ is a function whose domain is (or sometimes contains) $A$, and the image of $A$ under $f$ is (or sometimes is contained in) $B$.

We say $f$ is **injective** if for any two outputs in the image of $f$, they are guaranteed to have come from two different inputs in the domain of $f$.

---

This is one of the annoying bits of notation. An "onto" function is surjective, but there's no such thing as an "into" function. This lack of notational symmetry is why I avoid the term "onto".